# How do I get Amazon Health Status via an API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

Is it possible to get Amazon web services health api flags via an API. Their RSS feed does not mention the actual status of the given service.

I am looking for a possible API which returns,

1. Service is operating normally
2. Performance issues
3. Service disruption
4. Informational message

I rather read an answer which points me to the documentation which I may have skipped. At last if nothing I might go down to the screen scrapping path. However it isn't viable at all.

Any thoughts.

Comment: the `screen scrapping path` seems to be the way as amazon don't provide an api for what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently an API for this. I have asked them before for cloudwatch alerts or an API. Maybe it is in the pipeline?

However you can parse the RSS feed, easily with something like google feed api:
https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/

If there are no posts assume, service is operating normally. Otherwise read the text of the "post's" title parsing on the ":" the first half is the status.

for example if your latest post is

```
<item>
  <title type="text">Performance issues: Route 53 Elevated API Error Rate</title>
  <link>http://status.aws.amazon.com</link>
  <pubDate>Wed, 16 Jan 2013 19:43:43 PST</pubDate>
  <guid>http://status.aws.amazon.com/#route53_1358394223</guid>
  <description>We are continuing to work to resolve elevated error rates to our control API. This does not impact queries to existing DNS records.</description>
 </item>
```

Then your status is "Performance issues" until you recieve a new post with a title starting "service operating normally"

Comment: Good Idea still it would be very time consuming task to get 192 xmls GET process and then dispose. I will make a request for API too...Hopefully they will notice if multiple people are asking for it. Thanks

Comment: Pity there's not some kind of subscribable  SNS topic that generates notifications of AWS status changes.